# ClassNotFoundException when inflating non-compatibility fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My application keeps crashing on launch due to what seems to me to be an odd error. I have included the logcat below as well as the relevant layout but as you can see there is an inflate exception caused by a class not found exception for class `android.view.fragment`. I am not using compatibility fragments (the app does not support pre-ICS) and so everything is expecting `android.app.Fragment`. All of the other posts I have been able to find suggest using `FragmentActivity` but that is not a solution here as we do not use the support library. Does anyone have any insight?

The layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/locations"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Some views here -->

    <!-- The line below is line 38 referenced in the LogCat -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ad_fragment"
        android:name="tenkiv.billing.AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/ad_fragment_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the LogCat output:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tenkiv.environment.application/com.tenkiv.environment.application.EnvironmentMainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.setMenu(SlidingMenu.java:384)
    at com.tenkiv.environment.application.EnvironmentMainActivity.onCreate(EnvironmentMainActivity.java:335)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.fragment" on path: /data/app/com.tenkiv.environment.application-2.apk
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Did try do a project wide search for `"android.view.fragment"` to see if it occurs anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure by try giving fully qualified name like this

```
 <fragment android:id="@+id/fragmentDetails" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
class="tenkiv.billing.AdFragment"/>
```

Comment: Results in a inflate exception "Class is not a View"

Comment: is tenkiv.billing.AdFragment this your custom class that extends fragment..?

Comment: Is your class in which you are using fragment using Extends FragmentActivity?

Comment: I thought it might be the <fragment section, but that seems to be valid Android XML. The fully-qualified class seems like it should do the trick as this answer shows.

Comment: adding fully qualified name as class tag rather than android:name made no difference. Still ClassNotFound on "android.view.fragment". No it does not extend FragmentActivity as that is only for compatibility library which I am not using. I have tried doing that anyway but it made no difference.

Comment: It should extend FragmentActivity of the support library...if there is effect or if not ..it should extend FragmentActivty

Comment: if ICS Activity class can handle fragments and I use ICS fragments, what does FragmentActivity bring to the table?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that in your FragmentActivity class you also call the onCreate method from the super class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be caused by silly things like typos or strange invisible characters getting injected in your xml tags. In my case, the cause was a typo in my "fragment"  opening tag.  I had "frsgment" instead and of course Android Studio didn't raise a flag.  It took me a while to figure out. Not good!